# Multivariable Linear Regression Coefficient

Tags: linear-regression, multinomial-coefficients

I have a dataset something like this:

```
A       B     C      D      E         coef to A
1900  0.23   0.98   0.55    1         B  51
1530  0.47   0.76   0.46    1         C  62
2300  0.26   0.86   0.13    0         D  53
1430  0.24   0.66   0.76    0         E  55
2440  0.05   0.88   0.45    1
```

And when I form my model (with StatsModels Python) to predict A

I get E with a 100+ number for a coefficient, others around 51-56. E is a bivariable (0, 1) but not sure how I should transform it if I should at all. How should I handle this?
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F401m.png) With E

```
                                 OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                tuition   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.927
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.927
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                              3659.
Date:                Tue, 10 Dec 2019   Prob (F-statistic):                        0.00
Time:                        14:30:59   Log-Likelihood:                         -10794.
No. Observations:                1155   AIC:                                  2.160e+04
Df Residuals:                    1151   BIC:                                  2.162e+04
Df Model:                           4                                                  
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                                  
==================================================================================
                     coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pcttop25          51.4044      4.607     11.157      0.000      42.365      60.444
graduat           57.3034      4.684     12.235      0.000      48.114      66.493
alumni            56.7086      8.162      6.948      0.000      40.695      72.723
public/private  3120.7245    192.468     16.214      0.000    2743.097    3498.352
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       16.130   Durbin-Watson:                   1.461
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               23.647
Skew:                           0.127   Prob(JB):                     7.33e-06
Kurtosis:                       3.653   Cond. No.                         204.
==============================================================================
```

Without E

```
                                 OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                tuition   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.910
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.910
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                              3903.
Date:                Tue, 10 Dec 2019   Prob (F-statistic):                        0.00
Time:                        14:23:06   Log-Likelihood:                         -10913.
No. Observations:                1155   AIC:                                  2.183e+04
Df Residuals:                    1152   BIC:                                  2.185e+04
Df Model:                           3                                                  
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                                  
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pcttop25      43.3553      5.075      8.544      0.000      33.399      53.312
graduat       85.6925      4.813     17.806      0.000      76.250      95.135
alumni        90.4125      8.744     10.340      0.000      73.256     107.569
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       16.562   Durbin-Watson:                   1.479
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               17.476
Skew:                           0.257   Prob(JB):                     0.000160
Kurtosis:                       3.314   Cond. No.                         8.65
==============================================================================
```

Comment: You are trying to predict tuition, and this binary variable would be a change in the constant of the model. I'm not exactly sure what the private/public binary variable includes, but a change in the constant of the model of 3k dollars does not seem off to me. Do you have any specific reason to suspect of this coefficient in particular?

Comment: private/public is just 0 (Public) or 1 (Private)
It's just very large and so is it's std err.

Comment: I think you should think of it in terms of your dependent variable. You are trying to model tuition. Specifically, when your binary variable is one, that coefficient "appears" as a constant, and changes the constant of the model. This is exactly the change in the expected value of tuition that comes from it being a private school, holding everything else constant. It is then not surprising that the coefficient is around 3000, because then: "the difference in the expected value of the tuition given that it is a private institution is three thousand dollars". Is it clearer now?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.